# Android background with shadow on all sides

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Android'd `CardView` provides an `elevation` property but the casted shadow is at an angle and thus only shows at the bottom of the view. I'd like to cast a shadow on all sides for a pill-shaped view.

Like so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by adding the following attributes to your CardView tag in XML

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
card_view:cardElevation="16dp"
```

if 16dp is small for you, you can make it higher

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, this only sets the shadow at an angle. I need it cast equally on all sides

Comment: @najm I believe that the code I posted will give you the result that you want. or else I hope you don't mind to share a screenshot with me

Comment: thanks for the answer. It certainly came close but as you'll see in there screenshot [here](https://i.imgur.com/0Qe9ID9.png), the shadow is heavier on the bottom than on any other side. As far as I know, `CardView` does not let you change the angle of the shadow. I would like the shadow to be equally distributed on all sides.